# Using testcomplete to determine if a mobile app used the correct icon

Tags: android, testcomplete

I just started using TestComplete and have a technical question for the experts out there. My mobile app has an icon that changes based on state (pressed, not pressed, disabled, etc). What I would like to do is be able to have a keyword test (ideally) to determine if the app is displaying the correct icon. I can start the app and press the icon just fine so I believe I have the app instrumented correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a region checkpoint to validate that the correct image matches the state of your button.
[https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/testing-with/checkpoints/regions/creating.html][1]

Please let me know if this doesn't help!